# How to change woocomerce or full wordpress currency with value from USD to AUD

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Well In my wordpress site I want to change my currency USD to AUD with value . By value I mean it will trun 1 dollar = 1.53 AUD dollar . and it will change automatic. Cus I have 600+ product but it not possible to change one by one . And i have just decide to sell on Australia.

Can you please help me to write sql query or something like this